# Создать программу с++ с циклами

Tags: c++, visual-c++

У меня есть функция: y=(lg2*x)/x.
X принадлежит промежутку [2,5; 10], каждую итерацию увеличивается на 1.5, я пытался написать программу, вот что получилось (выдает ошибку):

```
#include "stdofx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
For(int x=2.5;x<=10;x=x+1.5)
cout<<"y"<<(log10(2*x))/x<<endl;
system("pause")
return 0;
}
```

Visual code c++ 2008, знаю, старьё, но что поделать, там, где я учусь, компы с windows Хp, так что лучше у них, наверное, не потянет.

Comment: Если это не поможет, то текст ошибки в студию.

Comment: Божественный код, особенно For(int x=2.5;x<=10;x=x+1.5). вместо инта надо было string попробовать взять....

Comment: @Beeen007 интересно, как вы строкой то хотите эту задачу решить?

Comment: @Miron Сарказм не был понят ....

Comment: @Beeen007 Смайлик бы хоть добавили. Зря вы над новичком смеетесь.

Comment: @Miron ну такое....

Comment: @Beeen007 Вы же видите его уровень, вы можете его запутать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибки:

1 - в int кладете float (почитайте про усечение значения)

2 - #include "stdofx.h" зачем?

3 - не подключили библиотеку с лог

вот код с исправлениям...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>


int main ()
{
    double x{2.5};
    double step{1.5};

    while (x <= 10) {
        std::cout << "x : " << x << " y : " << log10(2*x) / x << std::endl;
        x += step;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вариант с for (по заявкам)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>


int main ()
{
    for (double x{2.5}; x <= 10; x += 1.5) {
        std::cout << "x : " << x << " y : " << log10(2*x) / x << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for как-то логичнее подошел бы.

Comment: While.. спасибо. А как сделать с помощью команды For эту же задачу?

Comment: @Witalik см. обновление

Comment: Так же, как это сделал автор. for(double x = xBegin; x <= xMax; x+=xStep){}

Comment: @Witalik обновите страницу и посмотрите 2ой вариант

Comment: а в чём смысл писать `double x{2.5}` а не `double x = 2.5`? Редко такой стиль вижу просто, интересно.

Comment: @pavel - это не стиль, это инициализация значением, а то что Вы написали - это инициализация дефолтным значением и присвоение.

Comment: @Beeen007 в данном контексте, записи эквиваленты. Инициализацию дефолтным значением компилятор делает в случае статической переменной, либо в случае инициализации конструктором по умолчанию. В нашем же случае, речь идет о переменной на стеке.