# Создать программу с++ с циклом do/while

Tags: c++

Моя функция: `y = exp(x)/(x+2)`

X принадлежит диапазону `от 5 до 11 включено`, при каждом проходе цикла Х становится больше на 1.2.

Я пытался написать (выдает ошибку):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int x = 5;
    do {
        cout << "y=" << exp(x)/(x+2) << endl;
        x += 1.2
    } while(x <= 11);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Visual code c++ 2008, знаю, старьё, но что поделать? Там, где я учусь, компы с windows Хp, так что лучше у них, наверное, не потянет.

Comment: Вы бы хоть написали, какая ошибка, а то телепатов тут мало, они нарасхват. Кстати, а почему у Вас int x??? Учитывая, что работаете Вы явно с float (1.2, как минимум...)

Comment: Компилятор VC++ выводит следующее: **.cpp(8): error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "}"** - какое слово вам здесь непонятно? Номер строки есть, описание ошибки есть... Чего вам не хватает для понимания?

Comment: Пишите код с нормальным форматированием. Это ужасно. Вы пропустили ; из-за того, что вы не соблюдаете форматирование.

Comment: @Miron Думаю, в данном конкретном случае - при всей верности совета - это не сильно помогло бы...

Comment: Что поделать, я начинающий программист учусь на ошибках... Что уж поделать, но если бы я не хотел чему-то научиться, не обратился на данный сайт. Готов принять любую (желательно адекватную критику. @Miron подскажите как должно выглядеть нормальное форматирование по вашему мнению.

Comment: @Witalik это для начала: https://tproger.ru/translations/stanford-cpp-style-guide/ . Посмотрите, как фигурные скобочки циклов пишутся, какие отступы используются.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Создать программу с++ с циклами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1044595/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%81-%d1%81-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Comment: Дубликат. Вам уже вчера ответили на такой-же вопрос с другими значениями

Comment: @Beeen007 Это схожий вопрос. Приношу извинения. Пойду, отредактирую чтобы StackOverglow не ругался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x+=1.2
```

Забыл про точку с запятой перед while